# Getting out of range exception in Substring c#

Tags: c#, string, substring

i am trying to print the Filename from last index of '//' till the file length.
[image: Image where length of F1 ans idx and file] 
file length is coming as 83 last index is coming as 47 then what wrong i am doing here

```
int idx = file.LastIndexOf('\\');
int fl=   file.Length;
string filename = file.Substring(idx, fl);
```

Comment: Why not use [`Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) instead?

Comment: [rtfm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)-question

Answer (score 2):

[Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) is not "from", "to" but "from", "length".

Starting at index 47 and 83 characters long is way out of the range of your current string.

If you want the rest of the string anyway, use

```
string filename = file.Substring(idx);
```

That said, C# has nice APIs for doing this. Use the [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) class whenever possible and don't do this manually.

Answer (score -1):

first of all see the substring argumants

```
public string Substring(
int startIndex,
int length
```

)
starting index was 47 and length was 83

if u want get file name,you can use the [GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Look at available answers before posting new

Comment: when i start typing there is not available answer,but thanks

Comment: I'd recommend not answering basic questions altogether. It's a, as Tim phrased, "rtfm-question" and didn't really need an answer, but a close-vote (you'll get those with a bit more reputation).